# build/auth0.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angular, auth0

I'm trying to follow the instructions for integrating auth0 into my Angular 
application [from this tutorial](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2)

Unfortunately, the instructions there have lots of gaps. When I launch my application or try to perform an authentication, I get the following in the Chrome developers console:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/auth0-js/build/auth0.js 
net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

I am able to run the sample app that they generate for you, but that doesn't help me much. I'd like to be able to follow the steps provided and incrementally build the application.

Can anyone help me understand what the problem might be?

Thanks

Comment: You are referring to the wrong URL, make sure that you've defined it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove this line from your project:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/auth0-js/build/auth0.js"></script>
```

and place "node_modules/auth0-js/build/auth0.js" into script block in "angular.json".

```
....
"scripts": [
    "src/client/assets/someExampleScript.js",
    "node_modules/auth0-js/build/auth0.js"
],
....
```

Please [look at that](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts).